# Install BeautifulSoup, mrjob, pattern, and seaborn on python 2.7 on Jupyter

Tags: ipython, seaborn, mrjob, jupyter

I am learning how to use the new [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/). I want to install packages:BeautifulSoup, mrjob, pattern, and seaborn on python 2.7. I first tried to do so by running `pip install BeautifulSoup mrjob pattern seaborn`  That all returns: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I also tried `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`, it did work for Beautifulsoup. But I still don't know how to install other packages.

Wondering anyone know why there was syntax error for using `pip install`? Is that because I haven't installed pip on python 2.7?

Comment: Sounds like you're running `pip` from inside Jupyter. It's a command line program, so you should run it from a terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also able to install these packages from iphython notebook window by running

```
import pip    
def install(package):
   pip.main(['install', package])

install('BeautifulSoup4')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing one package at a time. This helps you find which installation command not working.

You can find Julia packages [here](http://pkg.julialang.org/).

Comment: I did install them one at each time, so that is not the problem. But still thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was running pip from inside Jupyter. However, Jupyter is a command line program. Thanks to Mwaskom, the solution is run it from a terminal using:

```
pip install BeautifulSoup mrjob pattern seaborn
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
!pip install BeautifulSoup mrjob pattern seaborn
```